# Bolt-on crate motor not bolting on

Tags: engine-swap, chrysler-300c

Barb cooked the 5.7 Hemi on our 2008 Chrysler 300c. A broken heater hose was the cause. We purchased a 5.7 hemi crate motor that is 2011. This motor has VVT. The old blown Hemi just has cylinder reduction. The camshaft timing chain front cover is not mechanically compatible so they cant be swapped. The new engine should be better but I am worried about ECU issues. These bolt-on things are not really bolt-on. What else could I be in for?

Comment: The obvious comment is that there are differences between  a 2008 motor and a 2011 motor - you should have purchased a bolt-on 2008 motor... There may be differences for the bell housing as well as the ecu  etc.

Comment: You'll need an ECU and loom designed to work with your new engine.  The 2008 ECU won't understand the VVT hardware.

Comment: Get the correct motor for your vehicle.